# How to get the path to the current directory? (ScriptableObject, UnityEditor.AssetDatabase)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

Sorry for my English (Google Translate). The following is a snippet of code that creates an asset (ScriptableObject) in the selected directory (Assets/Resources/TestObject.asset):

```
[MenuItem("Assets/Create/Test Object")]
private static void CreateTestObject()
{
    var testObject = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<TestObject>();
    AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(testObject, "Assets/Resources/TestObject.asset");
    AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
}
```

How can I get the path to the directory I'm in? In order to don´t hardcode the path manually, but to save this GameObject in the same folder where I call the method.

---

For example:

1) I call the method from *Assets/TestFolder/TestFolder2*.

2) And in this same directory it creates an asset (TestObject). And does not create in *Assets/Resources*.

To sum up, I need to get the path to the directory in which I called the method through the menu (*Assets/Create/Test Object*).

---

Additionally: Can I immediately rename the GameObject after creating it? As with other objects (*scripts, folders, etc.*).

Thanks in advance for your answers!

---

[Example (screenshot):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFttw.png)
How do I get the path that is highlighted in red. I'll call the method through the menu (*Create/Test Object*). In the directory I have chosen (*Assets/TestFolder/TestFolder2*). And the asset is created there. And not in *Assets/Resources*. I need a method that will return a string to me: *Assets/TestFolder/TestFolder2*.

Answer (score 3):

While HedgehogNSK's answer is certainly correct, you may find yourself in a situation where you want to create an asset in the current folder outside the context of a `Create` menu (for instance, via a custom `EditorWindow`). In this case, you can use the same method the editor does internally, `ProjectWindowUtil.CreateAsset(Object asset, string path)`. This will both create an asset from the provided object and give the user a chance to rename it, just like the default entries under `Create` do. Example:

```
private static void CreateTestObject()
{
    var testObject = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<TestObject>();
    // Do some custom initialization logic for testObject
    ProjectWindowUtil.CreateAsset(testObject, "TestObject.asset");
}
```

The `ProjectWindowUtil` class is not documented, but is `public` and can be readily found in the Unity Reference Source [here](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/61f92bd79ae862c4465d35270f9d1d57befd1761/Editor/Mono/ProjectWindow/ProjectWindowUtil.cs#L219). `CreateAsset` in particular has existed for several years now, so it is probably safe to assume it's not going anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Use `[CreateAssetMenu]` for creating `ScriptableObject`, instead of `[MenuItem]`.
When you use `CreateAssetMenu` attribute it adds option to Assets -> Create which creates object in current folder.

```
[CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "MyApp/TestClass")]
public class TestClass: ScriptableObject
{
}
```

Comment: Sometimes that is not an option, for example if creation requires additional steps before the file is created.